# Excel-VBA SQL query returns blank when even if there is one record in the column

Tags: sql, vba, excel

***I'm writing a SQL query in Excel VBA but it returns blank column (doesn't read the value)***

**Query - Select Distinct [Column1] from [TableName]**

There are 29k rows in the [Column1], out of which Row #48 has some value and all other are null (Blank). The code above returns only null (Blank) value. However i Tested some cases and following are my observations -

1.If I copy the value from Row #48 and move to Row #1 (deleting the
    original value at Row#48), the query works

2. If I add some other values in the column, the query works and sometimes it doesn't depending on which Rows I add the Value in
3. I've checked the Range of [TableName], it covers the required columns and Rows
4. The query works fine on columns which have multiple values
5. Tried changing format of the cells but didn't help

**Appreciate it if someone could tell me why is this happening and How should i go ahead Correcting this.**

Comment: Can you show the sql query?

Comment: Does the query work if the value is moved to row 2 (ie checking to see if it only works if some data is in row 1)?  Also, are there other columns in the table and do they have values in the rows where [Column1] is blank/null?

Comment: I'm checking the results using a simple query which is - " Select distinct [territory] from [RawData$A10:ES29100]"

Comment: @mcalex yes it works when i write something in row #2. i tried some random row #s - It does not work around row 40 or something

Answer (score 2):

From:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/setting-options-programmatically-for-the-excel-driver?view=sql-server-2017

> Rows to Scan  The number of rows to scan to determine the data type of
>   each column. The data type is determined given the maximum number of
>   kinds of data found. If data is encountered that does not match the
>   data type guessed for the column, the data type will be returned as a
>   NULL value.
>
> For the Microsoft Excel driver, you can enter a number from 1 to 16
>   for the rows to scan. The value defaults to 8; if it is set to 0, all
>   rows are scanned. (A number outside the limit will return an error.)

Likely what is happening is the Excel driver scans the first x rows, guesses a data type, then the later rows don't match that type and so get assigned as null.  This is why moving the value up fixes the problem.  Try setting to scan all rows.

Comment: Maybe also see:  https://www.concentra.co.uk/blog/why-ssis-always-gets-excel-data-types-wrong-and-how-to-fix-it

Comment: It would be really helpful if you can also provide the example for the connection string  with TypeGuessRows set to 0.

Comment: I Tried the following connection string but it didn't help                              
      With cnn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .Properties("Extended Properties") = "excel 12.0;IMEX=1;MAXSCANROWS=0; TYPEGUESSROWS=0"
        .Properties("Data Source") = ThisWorkbook.FullName
        .Properties("Jet OLEDB:DataBase PassWord") = PWD
        .Open
    End With

Comment: TypeGuessRows is a registry setting

Comment: Try adding the IMEX setting.

Answer (score 0):

The Setting is here: \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Access Connectivity Engine\Engines\Excel

I have changed "TypeGuessRows" from 8 to 0, and now the queries work!